# Can't post data to Express using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

This is my first time trying to make a full stack app. I already have experience with Django but now i wanted to try using Express.js 
So, i made this simple route in express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var User = require('../User/User');


app.use(logger("short"));

app.post("/addUser", (req, res) => {
User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({auth: false})
    res.status(200).json(
        {
            email,
            name
        }
        );
    });
});
```

this is the User schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
    },
    {timestamps: true}
);
mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User");
```

I already tried doing some post requests using insomnia. They all worked
But when i make a post request using react it creates an object but its name, email, password fields are empty, like this:

```
createdAt: "2018-11-22T16:59:51.844Z"
updatedAt: "2018-11-22T16:59:51.844Z"
__v: 0
_id: "5bf6e0878bd6663807e57dec"
```

this is my react code - it's in a func that's called when the form is submitted - (I already added the express server as a proxy):

```
    axios.post('/api/auth/addUser', {
        name:  register_name,
        email: register_email,
        password: register_password
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I get code 200 on express' console but the obj doesn't have any data.
Can you help me? -  I'm still a  beginner to React and Express

Edit: React Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
       this.state = {
        register_name: "",
        register_email: "",
        register_password: ""
    }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { register_name, register_email, register_password } = this.state
    axios.post('/api/auth/addUser', {
        name:  register_name,
        email: register_email,
        password: register_password
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

    console.log(this.state)

    this.clearInputs();

}

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <form method={"POST"} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id={"register-form"}>
                <label htmlFor={"register_name"}></label>
                <input type={"text"} name={"register_name"} id={"register_name"} placeholder={"name"} value={this.state.register_name} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                <label htmlFor={"register_email"}>Email</label>
                <input type={"email"} name={"register_email"} id={"register_email"} placeholder={"email"} value={this.state.register_email} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                <label htmlFor={"register_password"} >Password</label>
                <input type={"password"} name={"register_password"} id={"register_password"} placeholder={"password"} value={this.state.register_password} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                <button type={"submit"}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: any console entries? maybe a CORS issue?

Comment: You  are taking the info to submit from the state of the component `name: this.state.name` *etc*, are you sure it is correctly populated  ? Show the code of that component.

Comment: Just added the code of the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a series of potential problems here. First, there's no particular need to make a urlencoded form submission here: just use JSON. Your submit could then look something like:

```
handleSubmit (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const { email, name, password } = this.state
  axios.post('/api/auth/adduser', {
      email,
      name,
      password
    })
    .then(res => /* ... */)
    .catch(err => /* ... */)
}
```

On the server, you're probably after `res.json` rather than `res.send`.

```
const { email, name, password } = req.body
// ...
res.status(201).json({
  email,
  name
})
```

Also note that you don't need `bodyParser` these days (you can just use [`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)).

Finally, you should use `event.target.name` in your `handleChange` as the names match the names of your values in component state:

```
handleChange (e) {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: event.target.value })
}
```

### Simple example

Client:

```
const CLEAR_STATE = {
  email: '',
  name: '',
  password: '',
  message: ''
}

export default class App extends Component {
  state = CLEAR_STATE

  handleChange = e => this.setState({
    [ e.target.name ]: e.target.value
  })

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { email, name, password } = this.state
    axios.post('/', { email, name, password })
      .then(({ data }) => this.setState({
        ...CLEAR_STATE,
        message: `You sent: ${data.email}, ${data.name}, ${data.password}.`
      }))
      .catch(({ message }) => this.setState({ message }))
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='email'
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input
            type='text'
            name='name'
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input
            type='password'
            name='password'
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type='submit' value='Register' />
        </form>
        {this.state.message && <p>{this.state.message}</p>}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Server:

```
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body
  res.status(201).json({ name, email, password })
})
```

Comment: Ok, changed everything but now i get status code 500 -Cannot read property 'register_name' of undefined ( i changed all the names to register_name ecc)

Comment: `handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { register_name, register_email, register_password } = this.state
        axios.post('/api/auth/addUser', {
            name:  register_name,
            email: register_email,
            password: register_password
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

        console.log(this.state)

        this.clearInputs();
    
    }` This is the handler

Comment: You appear to have skipped adding `app.use(express.json())` in your server-side code. This is why your `req.body` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `[event.target.id]` of the changed `input` element to update the state.

You `state` expects `name`,`email`,`password` but receives `register_name`,`register_email`,`register_password`.

You should change the `id` of the `input` elements to match those in the state or you should use the `name` attribute since that is what matches .

```
this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
```

---

Keep in mind that the attribute `htmlFor` of the `label` elements also needs to match the `id` and not the `name` of the element it is linked to.

---

Also, you should have noticed that something was wrong since your code will not update the `input` elements while you type.

Comment: oh yeah, forgot i changed them haha. Anyway, changed everything, same result

Comment: @AbelHristodor again you name the post parameters `name`, `email`,`password` in the `axios` call, but in your server route you are using `req.body.register_name` to access them.

Comment: okk, but now i get ` Cannot read property 'name' of undefined```

Comment: @AbelHristodor you need `app.use(express.json());` in your server side script.

Comment: Okk thanks :) I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days and it got very frustrating haha

Answer (score 0):

Everything works out of the box with just bare `fetch`. 
Here is [gist](https://gist.github.com/bfunc/ac6d7455e99137852525a6bde148abe9), just make sure you attached [bodyParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to express instance

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

*axios lib is useful if you want to upload physical files with FormData*